# Откуда в массиве мусорные значения?

Tags: c++, массивы

нужно в теретий массив занести одинаковые значения с первого и второго
вроде как значения заносятся, но при выводе третьего массива выводятся "мусорные значения" -858993460

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    const int size = 10, size1 = 20;
    int massA[size], massB[size], massC[size1];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        massA[i] = rand() % 10;
        cout << massA[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        massB[i] = rand() % 10;
        cout << massB[i] << " ";
    }
    for (int z=0, i = 0; z<size, i < size; i++,z++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (massA[i] != massB[j]) {
                massC[z] = massA[i];
                cout << massA[i] << " ";
            }
        }

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size1; i++)
    {
        cout << massC[i] << " ";
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: там вместо size1 - size

Comment: если записываю так:<code>if (massA[i] != massB[j]) {
                massC[z] = massA[i];
                cout << massC[z] << " ";
}</code> ничего не меняется

Comment: Кстати, если `-858993460` представить как hex, то получите `0xCCCCCCCC`, что обычно свидетельствует о том, что память не инициализирована. В разных системах по-разному.

Comment: Просто интересно - зачем `for (int z=0, i = 0; z<size, i < size; i++,z++)` - полное и абсолютное дублирование `i` и `z`?

Comment: когда на начале для massC[size] присваиваю {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} - то в конце выводятся нули
по логике вроде бы все окей, но не работает должным образом
помогите плиз
а то от этой заминки с мусорными значениями не могу дальше продолжать делать задания

Comment: и там вместо  if (massA[i] != massB[j]) должно быть if (massA[i] == massB[j])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ваш массив massC заполняется значениями  в

```
if (massA[i] != massB[j]) {
                massC[z] = massA[i];
                cout << massA[i] << " ";
}
```

следовательно, не всегда, следовательно, в нем останутся мусорные значения, поскольку вы объявили, но не иницализировали массивы. в остальных массивах вы переписываете значения своими данными.

[вопрос-ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/629017) про инициализацию массивов нулями